# Slicing Numpy array using List

Tags: python, numpy

Consider 2D Numpy array `A` and in-place function `x` like

```
A = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
def x(M):
    M[:,2] = 0
```

Now, I have a list (or 1D numpy array) `L` pointing the rows, I want to select and apply the function `f` on them like

```
L = [0, 1]
x(A[L, :])
```

where the output will be written to A. Since I used index access to A, the matrix A is not affected at all:

```
A = array([[0, 1, 2],
           [3, 4, 5],
           [6, 7, 8]])
```

What I actually need is to slice the matrix such as

```
x(A[:2, :])
```

giving me the desired output

```
A = array([[0, 1, 0],
           [3, 4, 0],
           [6, 7, 8]])
```

The question is now, how to provide Numpy array slicing by the list `L` (either any automatic conversion of list to slice or if there is any build in function for that),  because I am not able to convert the list `L` easily to slice like `:2` in this case.

Note that I have both large matrix `A` and list `L` in my problem - that is the reason, why I would need the in-place operations to control the available memory.

Comment: Do you need to create a function to do this? Why not assign values directly by slicing without the function?

Comment: The reason is that my function is much more complicated than `M[:,2] = 0`

Comment: Would passing both the list and array as inputs to the function work?

Comment: I do not understand the question - the function `x` operates on 2D Numpy array like in the example above

Comment: Is the list of numbers always consecutive numbers?

Comment: no - otherwise, it would be easy to make slice from that

Comment: For instance, if the function takes inputs like `x(A, L)`, you could work within your function to do something like `A[L, 2] = 0`. If that doesn't make sense, perhaps we need more information to better understand your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the function so as you can pass slice `L` inside it:

```
def func(M,L): 
    M[L,2] = 0

func(A,L)

print(A)
```

Out:

```
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [3, 4, 0],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found that it is indeed not possible to make a slice from a list in general (e.g. https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html). An alternative solution (and maybe preferable for me) is to 
 rearrange the rows in `A` such that `L` would  refer to  consecutive sequence in the rearranged matrix.

Comment: @PavelProchazka no, AFAIK, even then `A[:3][:2]` might still give you a copy, and you can modify the original array.